# How to draw polygons in python (giving coordinates) and number its edges?

Tags: python, polygon, polygon-creation

I have a list of agroforestry plots (polygons) in python. Every polygon is represented as latitude/longitude.

```
polygon1_coords = [
    (11.946898956, -86.109286248),
    (11.947196373, -86.109159886),
    (11.947092456, -86.108962101),
    (11.946897164, -86.10886504),
    (11.946898956, -86.109286248 )]

polygon2_coords = [
    (11.946895372, -86.110055411),
    (11.94718204,  -86.110046254),
    (11.947194581, -86.109172705),
    (11.946900747, -86.109313718),
    (11.946895372, -86.110055411)
    ]
```

I need a way to draw those polygons as an image and place numbers on its edges. A polygon need to also be represented with a letter. This is an example of what I need

[image: What I need]

As you can see I need to be able to represent several polygons in the same picture and number its edges individually. How can I do it in python?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: If it for visualisation purposes only and they don't need to be spatially referenced, you can do it with MatPlotLib (or another plotting library). If they do need real-world locations then look into the Shapely or GeoPandas libraries (among others).